# Limiting recursion to certain level

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, recursion

I have a SQL table named Player and another called Team.

- Each Player MUST belong to a team via a foreign key `TeamID`.
- Each Team can belong to another Team via a recursive field `ParentTeamID`.

So it could be (top down)...

- TeamA
- TeamB
- Team76
- Group8
- Player_ME

My question is, if I'm given a Player's `PlayerID` (the PK for that table), what is the best way to get the top Team?

My query so far (which gets all teams):

```
WITH TeamTree
    AS (
        SELECT ParentTeam.*, Player.PlayerID, 0 as Level
        FROM Team ParentTeam
        INNER JOIN Player ON Player.TeamID = ParentTeam.TeamID
        WHERE Player.PlayerID IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(@PlayerIDs,','))
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT ChildTeam.*, TeamTree.PlayerID AS PlayerID, TeamTree.Level + 1
        FROM Team ChildTeam
                INNER JOIN TeamTree TeamTree
        ON ChildTeam.TeamID = TeamTree.ParentTeamID
    )
```

Now whilst I think this is the right place to start I think there may be a better way.  Plus I'm kinda stuck!  I tried using Level in a join (inside a subquery) but it didn't work.

Any ideas on how to work my way up the tree and get only the top level details?

Edit:

A ParentTeam CAN be a ParentTeam (infinite recursion), but a Player can only belong to one Team.

Data Structure
Team:
TeamID (PK), Name, ParentTeamID (Recursive field)

Player:
PlayerID (PK), Name, TeamID (FK)

Sample Data:

```
Team:
1, TeamA, NULL
2, TeamB, 1
3, Team76, 2
4, Group8, 3

Player:
1, Player_ME, 4
2, Player_TWO, 2
```

So with the above data, both players should show (in the query) that they have a "TopLevelTeam" of TeamA

Comment: What does `top team` mean? Can you show a few rows of sample data and show what results you want exactly?

Comment: So you are saying your current method works?

Comment: How deep can the teams be?  Can a parent have a parent?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've amended my question to include structure and sample data.

Comment: @AbeMiessler No, My current method shows all Teams which a player belongs to, but I only want the top most one (the one with a "NULL" ParentTeamID)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've amended my question, but in short, there is infinite recursion for Teams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for, with a bit of extra info thrown in for free :-)
Andrew had the correct idea in his edited version, but I think his implementation is incorrect.

The schema and query are available at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4a4e/10)

```
with teamCTE as (
  select TeamID,
         TeamName,
         cast(null as int) as ParentTeamID,
         cast(null as varchar(10)) as ParentTeamName,
         TeamID TopTeamID,
         TeamName TopTeamName,
         1 as TeamLevel
    from team
   where ParentTeamID is null
  union all
  select t.TeamID,
         t.TeamName,
         c.TeamID,
         c.TeamName,
         c.TopTeamID,
         c.TopTeamName,
         TeamLevel+1 as TeamLevel
    from team t
    join teamCTE c
      on t.ParentTeamID = c.TeamID
)
select p.PlayerID,
       p.PlayerName,
       t.*
  from player p
  join teamCTE t
    on p.TeamID = t.TeamID
```

**EDIT - answer to question in comment**

You can navigate to any level within the player's team hierarchy simply by joining to the CTE a 2nd time. In your case you asked for the 2nd top most team: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4a4e/18)

```
with teamCTE as (
  select TeamID,
         TeamName,
         cast(null as int) as ParentTeamID,
         cast(null as varchar(10)) as ParentTeamName,
         TeamID TopTeamID,
         TeamName TopTeamName,
         1 as TeamLevel
    from team
   where ParentTeamID is null
  union all
  select t.TeamID,
         t.TeamName,
         c.TeamID,
         c.TeamName,
         c.TopTeamID,
         c.TopTeamName,
         TeamLevel+1 as TeamLevel
    from team t
    join teamCTE c
      on t.ParentTeamID = c.TeamID
)
select p.PlayerID,
       p.PlayerName,
       t1.*,
       t2.TeamID Level2TeamID,
       t2.TeamName Level2TeamName
  from player p
  join teamCTE t1
    on p.TeamID = t1.TeamID
  join teamCTE t2
    on t1.TopTeamID = t2.TopTeamID
   and t2.TeamLevel=2
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhh, you work from the TOP and then work your way down to the player's team.  That is ingenious!  At first I thought it was voodoo! :)

Comment: One more quick question - If I wanted to get the second most top unit, how would I do that?  (Still part of the header for the question... lol)... I can open another question for that though if you like...

Comment: Sorry for this, but one more question, then I promise to leave you alone... I didn't phrase my last question correctly!  Looking at this SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fcda9/2  If I wanted everything from "TeamB" down (so forget about TeamA) and I want to represent "TeamB" as the TopTeam (I only have it's ID:2), how would I do that.  That's what I meant when I said "get the", I really should have said "get data from the second team down" !!   Again, happy to open another question if you want the points!

Comment: @Vijay - Just change the WHERE condition of the initial select in the CTE: `WHERE TeamID=2`. If that doesn't work, then I don't understand your request and you should ask another question.

Comment: @Vijay - 12 rows? I get 2 rows, one per player. See my 2nd SQL Fiddle. If you want info for a particular player, then simply add a WHERE clause to the main query: `WHERE p.PlayerID=1`.

Comment: I've already given you a link to a SqlFiddle where things aren't working (above), but post your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512805/limiting-recursion-to-certain-level-duplicate-rows

    That includes a different SqlFiddle and a bit more information...

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH TeamTree
    AS (
        SELECT ParentTeam.*, Player.PlayerID AS UrPlayerID, 0 as Level
        FROM Team ParentTeam
        INNER JOIN Player ON Player.TeamID = ParentTeam.TeamID
        WHERE Player.PlayerID IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.Split(@PlayerIDs,','))
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT ChildTeam.*, TeamTree.PlayerID AS PlayerID, TeamTree.Level + 1
        FROM Team ChildTeam
                INNER JOIN TeamTree TeamTree
        ON ChildTeam.ParentTeamID = TeamTree.TeamID /* These were reversed, I think */
           AND UrPlayerID=ChildTeam.PlayerID /* ADDED */
    )
```

Otherwise you get a huge duplication of rows, something like the square of the number of players, don't you?

--
(After comment below)
Quite right, I misread the schema. Look, you don't need to bring the player in until the very end. I thought the team tree arrangement might differ by player, but it doesn't. So

```
WITH recursive TeamTree AS (
   SELECT TeamID, ParentTeamID FROM Team T1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT T1.TeamID, T2.ParentTeamID FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.ParentTeamID=T2.TeamID
   )
 SELECT TeamTree.* FROM TeamTree JOIN Team T3 
      ON TeamTree.ParentTeamID=T3.TeamID WHERE T3.ParentTeamID IS NULL;
```

This gives you a table of each team and its root ancestor. Now join that to the player table.

```
SELECT * FROM Player JOIN  (WITH TeamTree AS (
       SELECT TeamID, ParentTeamID FROM Team T1
       UNION ALL
       SELECT T1.TeamID, T2.ParentTeamID FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.ParentTeamID=T2.TeamID
       )
     SELECT TeamTree.* FROM TeamTree JOIN Team T3 
          ON TeamTree.ParentTeamID=T3.TeamID WHERE T3.ParentTeamID IS NULL) teamtree2
     ON Player.TeamID=teamtree2.TeamID;
```

You can rejoin with `Team` if you need more columns.

Comment: The "AND UrPlayerID=ChildTeam.PlayerID /* ADDED */" part is an error as there is no equals, but even with that (or without that line at all) I get the lower unit.  So in your example (using my data) looking at player "Player_ME" returns "Group8" which is the lowest Team (right above the player)... I need it to return "TeamA".

Comment: Unfortunately I get The multipart identifier T1 could not be bound on this line "SELECT T1.TeamID, T2.ParentTeamID FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.ParentTeamID=T2.TeamID"  I've tried to fill in the blanks but I cant figure it out...

Comment: Try `FROM TeamTree T1 JOIN T2`. Unfortunately, I don't have good DB access from the office and I have trouble remembering the syntax for recursive queries.

Comment: Thanks for helping but dbbenham has a slightly different solution which I'm going to go with.  Again, thank you so much! :)